# How do I stay in a loop?

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

There are 3 documents with 'A+' blood group but it only shows one I think its because of all the returns which is causing to break the loop. When I check `print(snapshot.data());`, it shows me all 3 Documents but the function shows only one.

**Actual Result**:

```
{number: 9130313369, recovered_year: 2021, name: swojas bhalunkar, blood_group: A+, email: swojas12@gmail.com, recovered_month: 2, recovered_date: 2}
```

**Expected Result**:

```
{number: 1241324, recovered_year: 2021, name: swad, blood_group: A+, email: agadsgas, recovered_month: 5, recovered_date: 18}
{number: 13, recovered_year: 2021, name: swojas, blood_group: A+, email: swdq, recovered_date: 12, recovered_month: 5}
{number: 9130313369, recovered_year: 2021, name: swojas bhalunkar, blood_group: A+, email: swojas12@gmail.com, recovered_month: 2, recovered_date: 2}
```

Here's my code:

```
repeater(storeData, context) {
  return Builder(
    builder: (context) {
      return MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
          body: Card(
            child: ListView(
              children: [
                Text(storeData.toString()),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      );
    }
  );
}
getDocs(BuildContext context) async {
  final QuerySnapshot querySnapshot = await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Donation').where('blood_group', isEqualTo: 'A+').get();
  final List<QueryDocumentSnapshot> documentSnapshotList = querySnapshot.docs;
  var lengths = querySnapshot.docs.length;
  
  if(true){
    for (QueryDocumentSnapshot snapshot in documentSnapshotList) {
      var storeData = snapshot.data();
      print(snapshot.data());
      Navigator.push(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => repeater(storeData, context))
      );
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, could you please replace the image with the text version of the output? That way people can see it clearly and not be redirected to the image's site. Also, add a sample of your expected output as well if it's possible.

Comment: @Dondi sure i updated my post

Comment: Hi, could you also provide `build` function of the widget? I see `repeater` but can't understand how you use it, so it would be helpful to provide `build` method of the widget